# Change Modal Pop-up from ONLOAD to once per session

Tags: session, modal-dialog, popup, window

I got some nice code to make a CSS modal pop-up and changed it so that it loads  automatically with the page.  But I need to add some code to make it only appear once per session and not every time on every page.  I see on these pages lots of similar questions and solutions but I cannot quite get them to work on this code. Obviously there must be a way.  Any help useful. Thanks in advance.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
body {font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}

/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
display: none; /* Hidden by default */
position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
left: 0;
top: 0;
width: 100%; /* Full width */
height: 100%; /* Full height */
overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
position: relative;
background-color: #fefefe;
margin: auto;
padding: 0;
border: 1px solid #888;
width: 80%;
box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19);
-webkit-animation-name: animatetop;
-webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
animation-name: animatetop;
animation-duration: 0.4s
}

/* Add Animation */
@-webkit-keyframes animatetop {
from {top:-300px; opacity:0} 
to {top:0; opacity:1}
}

@keyframes animatetop {
from {top:-300px; opacity:0}
to {top:0; opacity:1}
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
color: white;
float: right;
font-size: 28px;
font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
color: #000;
text-decoration: none;
cursor: pointer;
}

.modal-header {
padding: 2px 16px;
background-color: #5cb85c;
color: white;
}

.modal-body {padding: 2px 16px;}

.modal-footer {
padding: 2px 16px;
background-color: #5cb85c;
color: white;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Animated Modal with Header and Footer</h2>

<!-- Trigger/Open The Modal 
<button id="myBtn">Open Modal</button>  -->

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

<!-- Modal content -->
<div class="modal-content">
<div class="modal-header">
  <span class="close">&times;</span>
  <h2>Modal top line</h2>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
  <p>Use this voucher code at the checkout for an extra 10% Off !</p>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
  <h3>bye!</h3>
</div>
</div>

</div>

<script>
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// Open the modal on load 
 onload = function() {
 modal.style.display = "block";
 }

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```